# Por qué tengo que hacer click para ver un objeto // Objeto oculto react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buenas para ver el nombre del comercio como se muestra en la imagen tengo que hacer click. Y quiero que salga directamente sin hacer click.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> *edito con el onClick*

```
  class Tickets extends React.Component {
  state = {
  tickets: [],
  clicked: false,
  };
  onclicked = () => {
this.setState({ clicked: true });
  };
     async AsignarComercio(data) {
  data.map(
  async (ticket) =>
    (ticket.nombre_comercio = (
      await getComercio(ticket.id_comercio)
    ).nombre_comercio),
);
 }
componentDidMount = async () => {
try {
  const data = await getAllTickets();
  await this.AsignarComercio(data);
  console.log('ticket');
  console.log(data);
  if (data) {
    this.setState({ tickets: data });
  }
} catch (err) {}
  };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Había pensado que fuera por el onClick pero no tiene sentido porque de ser así pasaría lo mismo con el precio y fecha.

Alguien sabría decirme? Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el método `this.onclicked`? Saludos

Comment: @g.4 ahí esta el método, que opinas

Comment: Creo que se te paso incluir otra vez el render, saludos

Comment: Efectivamente, falta ver el render para ver qué haces con el estado `clicked` pero tiene pinta que lo estás usando para mostrar esa texto extra ('Zara' en el ejemplo). Si es ese el caso con iniciar el estado `clicked` a true valdría.

Comment: vale es que no me dejaba la pagina poner tanto codigo vuelvo a meterlo